# docker compose permission issue

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm trying to start php7.4-apache container with certain permission settings which I got from this [article](https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/).
But ran into problem where my container stops with error:

In the article author says: "...you need to know just enough about the container you want to run that you can pinpoint which files and directories you need to update the owner for."

From google I understand sometimes this error occurs when port is busy, but I'm sure that's not my case because if you comment in Dockerfile permissions part, it works fine.

Please give me a hint what do I miss.

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && pecl install \
        redis \
    && apt-get clean

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pgsql pdo_pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf



# permissions
RUN userdel -f www-data &&\
    if getent group www-data ; then groupdel www-data; fi && \
    groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} www-data &&\
    useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g www-data www-data &&\
    install -d -m 0755 -o www-data -g www-data /home/www-data
RUN chown --changes --silent --no-dereference --recursive \
                  --from=33:33 ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} /var/www/html /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
USER www-data
# /permissions
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: test_web
    build:
      context: ./web
      args:
      # from .env: 1000:1000
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-0}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-0}
    ports:
    - 3333:80
    volumes:
    - ./../src:/var/www/html
    links:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    container_name: test_postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - TZ='GMT+3'
      - PGTZ='GMT+3'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/mount:/home/postgres
  redis:
    container_name: test_redis
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  composer:
    container_name: test_composer
    image: composer:latest
    command: composer install
    volumes:
      - ./../src:/app
```

Comment: It looks like you don't `COPY` your application source code into your image?  Would I have to recompile the image if I ran it on a different system with a different local user ID?

Comment: @DavidMaze 1) The code of application is in src directory, why do I need to copy it into image? I got volumes set up.
2) why would you need to recompile? You will just need to change params in .env file of docker folder.